# Api to get facebook account billing infomation

Tags: facebook-graph-api

My app need to get information about billing information as show in attachement image.
[image]
We can get it by open link: https://www.facebook.com/ads/manager/account_settings/account_billing
after logined.
I searching around api document but still not yet found any api relate to. Pls show me how to get it by api.
Thank in advance.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account  - see the `balance`, `funding_source_details`, etc. parameters.

Comment: Thanks, let me try then update you soon